# How to render text over the QOpenGLTexture?

Tags: qt, opengl, text, textures, glut

So my task is to render some text over the texture in QOpenGLWidget.
I'm using simple `glutBitmapCharacter` for text and it works fine without texture, but when i'm adding texture before the text like that:

```cpp
// in initializeGL
QOpenGLTexture t = new QOenGLTexture(img);
t->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::LinearMipMapLinear);
t->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);

// in printGL
t->bind();
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, 255);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2i(255, 255);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2i(255, 0);
glEnd();
```

... it starts showing me texture without any text.
Do i need to somehow unbind the texture after usage or what?

Comment: i tried to use `release` method, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two-dimensional texturing has to be enabled, see [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml):

```cpp
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

If texturing is enabled, then by default the color of the texel is multiplied by the current color, because by default the texture environment mode (`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`) is `GL_MODULATE`. See [`glTexEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml).

This causes that the color of the texels of the texture is "mixed" by the last color which you have set by [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

Set a "white" color before you render the texture, to solve your issue:

```
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Disable 2 dimensional texturing after drawing the quad:

```cpp
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2i(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2i(0, 255);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2i(255, 255);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2i(255, 0);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: so i did what you've said, but there is still just a texture

Comment: Fixed! Seems like there was 2 problems. 1st one you helped me with. and the 2nd one, where the text coordinates were in the texture. i just moved them a bit closer then the texture.
Thanks for help!